# How do I solve the following errors: "Undefined reference to WinMain", "[Error] Id returned 1 exit status"?

Tags: c, dev-c++

I'm writing a C program and using Dev C++ to compile/run it.

However, it's coming up with the error:

```
undefined reference to 'WinMain'" and "[Error] Id returned 1 exit status"
```

What do these errors mean, and how do I solve them?

The `WinMain` error appears to be linked to line 18 of my code which is...

```
int read_char() { return getchar(); }
```

Any ideas? I'm a beginner with C, and I haven't found an answer to this question that I understand.

I presume it's because I'm using Windows. Would the code work on linux as it is perhaps?

Comment: I don't know "Dev C++" but shou should probably start a "Windows console" project or something like this.

Comment: How are you going to use `getchar()` function in window?

Answer (score 7):

This error means that the linker is looking for a function named [`WinMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559.aspx) to use as the entry point. It would be doing that because you configured the project to target the GUI subsystem, but did not provide a `WinMain` function.

My guess is that you want to produce a console application and have provided a `main` function. Target the console subsystem to resolve the problem.

Comment: I didn't configure the project at all really, I just copied and pasted the code from gedit. How do I produce a console appllication? I have provided a main function already.

Comment: How did you create the dev c++ project? A gui or a console project. Did you try to change the dev c++ config from gui to console?

Comment: I just did File -> New -> Source File I believe

Comment: You must have done more than that surely. There must be a project workspace for this IDE. Did you look in the config for your project yet? Please tell me what you have tried? Do you know the difference between console and GUI app?

Comment: Thanks. The problem for me was that I was m missing a main function.